# Why Popup part of combobox is resizable in one context and not in the other?

Tags: wpf, popup, custom-controls, resize

I have a wpf cusotm control derived from combobox System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox the control template is redefined and the popup (`PART_Popup`) contains a DataGrid and some other control. I use it in two places - in TabControl(,Grid) and in a Window(Grid,,Grid). When the DataGrid is resized either by dragging columns or from code the behavior is different: in window the Popup resizes in TabControl Popup remains the same and a scrollbar appears if necessary.

I need to know what can cause such difference.

**Edit**
Datagrid is has HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"

Comment: could you show your resize code ?

Comment: mPopupGrid.Width = 1000.0 I have added this to find what is gooing on. The main problem is column dragging.

Comment: No. I am resizing the grid in both cases and the Popup resizes (or not) automatically.

Comment: I apologize for confusing question. I resize columns but the problem is that the DataGrid resize as well. And problem is that in one case the Popup containing Datagrid resizes too.

Comment: @VincentPiel:  mPopupGrid.Columns(0).width=400 causes the same difference in behavior as dragging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it. By mistake there was

```
  Popup.Width=Me.Width
```

instead of

```
 Popup.Width=Me.ActualWidth
```

This caused resizability in case when the `Me.Width` was not set.